# Android System-GUI eventlistener

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Is it possible to implement a event based 'system-gui' listener in an Andriod app on a not rooted device?
If yes, is there any documentation about creating such listener?

Problem:
my application should notice if a call is answered by the other party, based on the fact that the GUI is changing. (Since the call-states can not be specified, I want to try this 'workarround') - but I do not know how I could implement a listener for special system UI parts.

Comment: Please try to describe this more detailed.

Comment: "my application should notice if a call is answered by the other party, based on the face that the gui is chancing" -- there is no requirement that there by any UI change that identifies that a call is answered, and there is no ability for you to get at that GUI anyway.

Comment: I want to implement a listener, which tells me, if a call is answered , through the fact, that the system UI changes a 'UI-part' - or changes the colour of a UI part. But i can not find a documentation which enables me to generate a gui listener for a 'not self generated UI'.

Comment: Okay -if there is no ability to implement a listener for the system UI -that was the answere i was afraid of. But thank you for the clearification!!